# How implement join queries in parse.com javascript?

Tags: parse-platform

I am new on parse server ( parse.com ). I have two classes "students_records" and "students_fee". I am storing fee records in class "students_fee" with objectId of "students_records" in column "student_id". Now I want to collect records from both classes by one query similar to join query we do in mysql with base on column 'fee_year' in class "students_fee". for example get all students who have 'fee_year'=2016 and 'student_id'=objectId of "students_records", this is link https://parseplatform.github.io/docs/js/guide/ of guide I am currently getting help, but i can't find such thing. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since parse use MongoDB (NoSQL) behind the scenes there is no real "join". What you can do is to create a array relationship from students to records and then use **include** in your query in order to include all the **records** under a student.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#relations).

I recommend you to use Parse SDK's here in order to keep it simple. 
the Parse SDK is available for all the popular programming languages (e.g. iOS, Android, PHP, JavaScript and more)