# Parse database Javascript How to get data from multiple tables when a column has same value

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, parse-server

I am new with Parse DB. Recently I am trying to get data from multiple tables like I have the Users table and Employee table, where User.objectId is equal to Employee.userid. I have tried many ways but did not get any results.

```
let query = new Parse.Query(Employee);
query.descending("updatedAt");
let userQuery = new Parse.Query(User);
userQuery.select("username", "firstName", "lastName", "profile1", "reporter");
query.matchesKeyInQuery("reporter", "reporter", userQuery);

return userQuery.find({
   success: function (results) {
       return results;
       },
       error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
       }
});
```

Is there any way to get data from multiple tables on Parse DB Javascript. I have tried to include User also but the query is blank.

Comment: You need to join the tables.

Comment: @Barmar yeah I know do you have any idea about it like how I can join?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39956280/how-implement-join-queries-in-parse-com-javascript

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/cy6cea/how-to-use-pointers-relations-parse-com-javascript-sdk

Comment: Parse.com is not a relational DB, so it doesn't actually have a built-in JOIN operation.

Comment: I have tried that way using include like coderwall but it's not working.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're trying to acheive with you query, but I think the solution is probably to just put a pointer to User on the Employee object. Then you can include the User in your Employee query and have all of the User data associated with any Employees that match your query

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get both the `User` data and the `Employee` data with a single query. Per definition you cannot get "data from multiple tables" because each Parse query operates on exactly one table. However, you can `include` objects from other tables when they are stored as pointers on the queried table. Or you can run multiple queries in parallel and thus get data from multiple tables.

In your case, I suggest the first mentioned soltion, which requires a change of the data scheme: instead of just storing the `userId` in `Employee` you should rather store a pointer to `User` (probably named `user`). This way you can run a query like this:

```
const query = new Parse.Query(Employee)
query.descending('updatedAt')
query.include('user')
const employee = await userQuery.first() // assuming that we have at least one Employee
const user = employee.get('user')
```

Please note that you cannot use the full set of query helpers with nested pointers, e.g. I think `select` won't work on `employee.user`.